Clojure ordering of hashmaps
Here’s my reps.edn file:
{
 :deps
 {
  org.clojure/data.json   {:mvn/version "2.4.0"}
  org.clojure/data.csv    {:mvn/version "1.1.0"}
  org.flatland/ordered        {:mvn/version "1.4.0"}
  metosin/jsonista {:mvn/version "0.3.8"}
  com.cognitect/transit-clj {:mvn/version "1.0.333"}
  }}

(ns ordering-json
  (:require
   [clojure.data.csv :as csv]
   [clojure.data.json :as json]
   [jsonista.core :as json2]
   [clojure.java.io :as io]
   [clojure.string :as string]
   [clojure.test :as t]
   [flatland.ordered.map :refer [ordered-map]]
   ))

(defn save-as-json [of data]
  (with-open [writer (io/writer of)]
    (json/write data writer)))

(defn read-f [f out]
  (let [data (json/read-str (slurp  f)
                            :key-fn (fn [k] (if (empty? k) "" k))
                            :map-fn ordered-map
                            )]
    (prn data)
    (save-as-json out data)))

(read-f "./data/standards.json" "./data/modified.json")

I’ve several json deserializers and somehow all of them are reordering the json when they read it in memory. Is there a way to preserve the order when reading the original file?
When I feed it a small file the order of the keys is maintained. But when I feed a large nested json file, the order is disrupted.

This question is similar to: Sort JSON/Map structure in clojure before serializing to string. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I think you should rewrite the subject/question so it is more clear, that you want to preserve the order for a round-trip of reading/writing JSON files (ignoring, that order is no thing by default both in JSON or Clojure). Also map-fn is no thing with c.d.j?

We've used baloon (https://github.com/roboli/balloon) in the past for some related tasks. Generally speaking, Clojure maps are not ordered, so you may be swimming upstream. You may also be interested in sorted-map (https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/sorted-map)

can you load your file or an example - where the order is disturbed?
